# How to compress images using trimage?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, images, write

I installed `trimage` to optimize images hosted on my websites with `nginx` However I'm getting the following error:

> [error] /var/www/resistfromday1.org/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/video-anti-trump-women_s-march-turns-*nasty*-in-washington_-d.c.-900x300.jpg not a supported image file and/or not writeable

using the following command:

```
sudo trimage -d /var/www/resistfromday1.org/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/, --directory=/var/www/resistfromday1.org/htdocs/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/
```

I also tried switching to the owner of the files "www-data" which apparently isn't possible =) & even putting the permissions of the images to 777. Same thing.

Can anyone perhaps tell me what foolish mistake I'm making here?
Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: Possibilities: (1) A bug in `trimage`. (2) Your file is not a JPEG file, despite having the `.jpg` extension (nor is it any other image format supported by `trimage`). (3) Your file uses JPEG features not supported by `trimage`.